# 101 town problem with connected road

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> There are $101$ towns 
>   There are $50$ roads entering each town and $50$ roads leaving each town. Each town is connected with every other town by a one way road. Prove that you can reach one from other by driving along at most two roads.

Please help without graph theoretic solution. I am thinking of applying contradiction. I am not being able to think of a solution.

Comment: Maybe try considering the general problem There are $2n+1$ towns and $n$ roads entering each town and $n$ roads leaving each town. Prove that you can reach one from other by driving along at most two roads. Now maybe induction or trying smaller $n$'s first to conclude something (though I'm just throwing ideas).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we want to go from $A$ to $B$. If there's a road connected $A$ to $B$ directly, we are done.

Suppose not. Then, there must exist a road from $B$ to $A$.
Now, let $C_1,C_2,...,C_{50}$ be $50$ cities such that there's a road from $A$ to $C_i$.
If there exists $i\in \{ 1,2,...,50\}$ such that there's a road from $C_i$ to $B$, we are done.
Suppose for a contradiction there isn't such road. Then for all $1 \le i \le 50$, each road is from $B$ to $C_i$. But there is also a road from $B$ to $A$ so there are $51$ roads out of $B$, which is a contradiction as required.

Comment: This perfectly makes sense! I just edited your answer to clarify what you were saying, I think you can accept your own answer. Good job :)